# Prove that $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $0$.

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose that $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of random variables such that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\mathbb{P}(X_n = 0) = 1 - 1/n\\\\
\mathbb{P}(X_n = -1) = \mathbb{P}(X_n = 1) = 1/2n
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Prove that $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $0$.

Here is my attempt.

We say that $X_{n}\xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}} 0$ iff for every $\varepsilon > 0$, the following limit holds:
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega : |X_{n}(\omega)| \geq \varepsilon\}) = 0 
\end{align*}

Let us study each possible case separately. If $\varepsilon > 1$, then the limit equals zero because $|X_{n}(\omega)| \leq 1$.

But then I got stuck. Can someone help me to finish such exercise?

Comment: How is your probability measure  defined? Is $P(\{0\})=0$?

Comment: @Feng sorry, I have miswritten the question . . . I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, then
$$\{\omega\in\Omega:|X_n(\omega)|\geq \epsilon\}=\{\omega\in\Omega:|X_n(\omega)|=1\}=\{\omega\in\Omega: X_n(\omega)=\pm1\}.$$
Hence
$$\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega:|X_n(\omega)|\geq \epsilon\})=\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega: X_n(\omega)=\pm1\})=\frac1{2n}+\frac1{2n}=\frac1n\to0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Let $ \varepsilon > 0$.  Then

$$\mathbb{P}(|X_{n}| \geq \varepsilon) \leq \mathbb{P}(|X_{n}| \neq 0) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X_n=0) = 1-(1-1/n) = 1/n \to 0$$